# Ubuntu freezing after changing resolution

Tags: nvidia, virtualbox, display, display-resolution

After I install Ubuntu on VirtualBox the default resolution is 800x600, but I wanted to make it 1080p so typed:

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-core

sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-utils virtualbox-guest-x11 virtualbox-guest-dkms
```

And it was unlocked to change resolution after reboot. It went all good in 1080p. Login ok. But when the Desktop loaded it completely froze.
Deleted and installed again.

It works ok until I change the resolution to 1080p. When that happens, changing resolution back to normal doesn't help.

Here are the settings in which Ubuntu works:

**System:**

```
Base memory: 4096MB
Processors: 6
Acceleration: VT-x/AM-V, Nested Paging, KVM Paravirtualisation
**Display:**
Video Memory: 16MB
Graphics Controller: VMSVGA
```

**Storage:**

```
Controller: IDE
IDE Secondary Master:[Optical Drive] Empty
Controller: SATA
SATA Port 0: Ubuntu.vdi(Normal, 9.98 GB)
```

**Specs of native PC:**

```
GeForce 1050Ti OC;
i5 8400;
8GB RAM;
```

How to solve the problem?

Edit: The version in which Ubuntu runs is Ubuntu Desktop 18.04 LTS.
Version of VirtualBox is 6.1.2

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number? Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please do not use Add Comment.